# how do I convert text to jsonB

Tags: postgresql

What is the proper way to convert any text (or varchar) to `jsonB` type in Postgres (version 9.6) ?

For example, here I am using two methods and I am getting different results:

Method 1:

```
dev=# select '[{"field":15,"operator":0,"value":"1"},{"field":15,"operator":0,"value":"2"},55]'::jsonb;
                                            jsonb                                             
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"field": 15, "value": "1", "operator": 0}, {"field": 15, "value": "2", "operator": 0}, 55]
(1 row)
```

Method 2 , which doesn't produce the desired results, btw:

```
dev=# select to_jsonb('[{"field":15,"operator":0,"value":"1"},{"field":15,"operator":0,"value":"2"},55]'::text);
                                              to_jsonb                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 "[{\"field\":15,\"operator\":0,\"value\":\"1\"},{\"field\":15,\"operator\":0,\"value\":\"2\"},55]"
(1 row)

dev=#
```

Here, it was converted to a string, not an array.
Why doesn't the second method creates an array ?

Comment: About **similar title but different problem**, *"convert sql-text to jsonb-string"* (the atomic datatype conversion), see https://stackoverflow.com/q/64974466/287948

Answer (score 40):

According to [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html):

> **to_jsonb(anyelemnt)**
>
> Returns the value as json or jsonb. Arrays and composites are
>   converted (recursively) to arrays and objects; otherwise, **if there is
>   a cast from the type to json, the cast function will be used to
>   perform the conversion; otherwise, a scalar value is produced**. For any
>   scalar type other than a number, a Boolean, or a null value, the text
>   representation will be used, in such a fashion that it is a valid json
>   or jsonb value.

IMHO you are providing a JSON formatted string, then you should use the first method.

```
to_json('Fred said "Hi."'::text)  --> "Fred said \"Hi.\""
```

If you try to get an array of element using to_json(text) you'll get the next error:

```
select *
from jsonb_array_elements_text(to_jsonb('[{"field":15,"operator":0,"value":"1"},{"field":15,"operator":0,"value":"2"},55]'::text));
```

> cannot extract elements from a scalar

But if you previously cast it to json:

```
select *
from jsonb_array_elements_text(to_jsonb('[{"field":15,"operator":0,"value":"1"},{"field":15,"operator":0,"value":"2"},55]'::json));

+--------------------------------------------+
|                    value                   |
+--------------------------------------------+
| {"field": 15, "value": "1", "operator": 0} |
+--------------------------------------------+
| {"field": 15, "value": "2", "operator": 0} |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 55                                         |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Well, you are talking about `json` , not `jsonb`. Also, with your example (Fred said Hi) I get incorrect results. And I don't understand the "if the data type is not built in" part, I am specifying `::text` and `text` is built in. Also which of two *conversion*s we are talking about? The one that converts my input to `::text`, or the one that parses this `::text` and creates a `json` object. Postgres documentation is not well done, If it would be clear enough I  wouldn't asking on SO.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I've looked at 9.3 version docs, but in fact the result is the same.

Comment: I can not cast it to array because I don't know what that `json` string will be containing. What if it is going to have an associative array? Under 9.6 version, my query produces different results.That's why I am asking, because I thought, that using `to_jsonb()` function I would receive a correctly parsed `jsonb` object, however this is not the case.

Comment: I've found cast works for me. Example. select cast('[{"field":15,"operator":0,"value":"1"},{"field":15,"operator":0,"value":"2"},55]' as jsonb);

Answer (score 19):

If your text is just a json format text, you could just explicitly cast it to json/jsonb like this:

select '{"a":"b"}'::jsonb

Answer (score 2):

### Atomic type conversion and CSV-to-JSONb

A typical parse problem in open data applications is to parse line by line a CSV (or CSV-like) text **into JSONB correct (atomic) datatypes**. Datatypes can be defined in SQL jargon ('int', 'text', 'float', etc.) or JSON jargon ('string', 'number'):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION csv_to_jsonb(
  p_info text,           -- the CSV line
  coltypes_sql text[],   -- the datatype list
  rgx_sep text DEFAULT '\|'  -- CSV separator, by regular expression
) RETURNS JSONb AS $f$
  SELECT to_jsonb(a) FROM (
      SELECT array_agg(CASE
          WHEN tp IN ('int','integer','smallint','bigint') THEN to_jsonb(p::bigint)
          WHEN tp IN ('number','numeric','float','double') THEN  to_jsonb(p::numeric)
          WHEN tp='boolean' THEN to_jsonb(p::boolean)
          WHEN tp IN ('json','jsonb','object','array') THEN p::jsonb
          ELSE to_jsonb(p)
        END) a
      FROM regexp_split_to_table(p_info,rgx_sep) WITH ORDINALITY t1(p,i)
      INNER JOIN unnest(coltypes_sql) WITH ORDINALITY t2(tp,j)
      ON i=j
  ) t
$f$ language SQL immutable;

-- Example:
SELECT csv_to_jsonb(
  '123|foo bar|1.2|true|99999|{"x":123,"y":"foo"}',
  array['int','text','float','boolean','bigint','object']
);
-- results  [123,   "foo bar", 1.2,    true, 99999,  {"x": 123, "y": "foo"}]
-- that is: number, string,   number,  true, number, object
```