# How to convert sql-text to jsonb-string?

Tags: json, postgresql, types, casting, jsonb

There does not seem to be an obvious way:

- `select 'a123'::text::jsonb` = *ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json*
- `select '"a123"'::text::jsonb` = **BAD string** because quoted
  check `select '"a123"'::text::jsonb = ('{"x":"a123"}'::jsonb)->'x'`
  to see that **non-quoted is the correct**.
- `select '123'::text::jsonb = ('{"x":123}'::jsonb)->'x';` = **NOT string**

I need '123' and 'a123' as **pure JSONb strings**.

---

PS: it is not a duplicate of [generic automatic-anything conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41924784/287948).

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The quoted version is THE valid jsonb string. IMHO there's no other un-quotated representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert untyped [string literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRING), that are *not* wrapped in double-quotes to `jsonb` (or `json`), use the [**`to_jsonb()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) (or `to_json()`) function:

```
SELECT to_jsonb(text 'a123');
```

Note that the input has to be a string type (`text`, `varchar`, ...), not an untyped literal. That's how Postgres knows you want a JSON *string*.

The above `text 'a123'` is one way to cast an untyped literal. There are others:

- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871)

For a direct cast to `json(b)`, Postgres expects valid JSON literals (with double-quoted *strings*):

```
SELECT '"a123"'::jsonb;
```

To translate each value to a specific JSON primitive, you can cast conditionally before the conversion. Example:

```sql
SELECT p, CASE WHEN i>2 THEN to_jsonb(p::numeric) ELSE to_jsonb(p) END AS x
FROM   unnest('{ab,12,12,1.2}'::text[]) WITH ORDINALITY t(p,i);
```

---

> `select '"a123"'::text::jsonb` = BAD string because quoted

To be precise, the result is *not* a string, but a `jsonb` value containing a JSON string. To get the string as Postgres data type `text`, you need the `->>` operator:

```
select 'a123'::text  = ('{"x":"a123"}'::jsonb)->>'x'
```

Or (comparing JSON values):

```
select '"a123"'::jsonb = ('{"x":"a123"}'::jsonb)->'x';
```

> I need '123' and 'a123' as pure JSONb strings.

So:

```
SELECT '"123"'::jsonb, '"a123"'::jsonb;
```

Both contain JSON ***strings***.

This also works:

```
SELECT '123'::jsonb;
```

.. but contains a JSON ***numeric***.

But this does not work:

```
SELECT 'a123'::jsonb;  -- error
```

.. because it's not a valid numeric literal.

The manual has a table of mappings between [*JSON Primitive Types and Corresponding PostgreSQL Types*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-TYPE-MAPPING-TABLE)

Comment: Hum... But the question is about "jsonB-string", not "how to cast to SQL-text"

Comment: I need to input SQL-strings   and preserve it into the database as **correct** JSONb types... I need to say to PostgreSQL: plese a *123* is JSONb string, plese a *a123* is JSONb string, etc.

Comment: jsonb strings (or json for that matter) are represented as double-quoted string literals. Other JSON primitives work without double quotes: `null`, `boolean` and `numeric`.

Comment: Ok, but how to input it? `select '"a123"'::text::jsonb = ('{"x":"a123"}'::jsonb)->'x'` is false, I need to input into database a non-quoted string.

Comment: Ah, that's the missing bit. I added the solution at the top.

Comment: Perfect!  Now `select to_jsonb(text 'hello') = ('{"x":"hello"}'::jsonb)->'x'` and it works also with 123.

Comment: OOPS! On Postgresql version 12.5 `select p, to_jsonb(text p) from unnest(array['12','ab']::text[]) t(p)` is a **syntax error**. Only works with literal constants, `select to_jsonb(text 'p')`.

Comment: Yes, that syntax variant only works for casting literals. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676871/939860